# Modify parameters of grubnetx64.efi

Tags: grub2, bootloader, grub-efi, pxe

I need to customize the `grub.cfg` path embed in **prefix** parameter of `grubnetx64.efi` file which I downloaded from here [GRUBNETX64.EFI](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/uefi/grub2-amd64/current/).
I need this for my network boot environment(PXE) setup.

I used this file to boot winpe and it works fine with the default directory which is `grub/grub.cfg`.
When I run `set` command in grub menu at network boot, I can see `prefix=(tftp, 192.168.1.254)/grub`.

What I need is `prefix=(tftp, 192.168.1.254)/grub-efi-xyz`

How is this **grubnetx64.efi** built?

When I built my own `grubnetx64.efi` with `grub-mkimage` command, after network boot with winpe, throws `BLInitializeLibrary error 0x0000001` but not with official **grubnetx64.efi** image.

I need the build steps for official `grubnetx64.efi` file.

Thanks!